# How to grant access to a database and all it's contents, even for objects are will be added in the future

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

In my scenario the user is the owner of the database and whatever is / will be in it should be fully accessible to him / her. But I don't want the user to have any access to anything outside of his/her own database.

As I mentioned the structure of the database would change over the time and I prefer not to reset the permissions for each table / schema / function added.

How can I grant such a permission in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You are looking for `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you please post that as an answer? If possible, please also tell me how to grant all privileges to an existing database, all the way through to the very last object (deep grant!?). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best answer is actually that, by default, the owner can always grant/revoke privileges on any database object.  So if all tables are owned by the database owner, then by default he or she will have all access to these but others may not.  The owner can also assign permissions as well.  So make sure all tables are created by that user and there is no problem.  For other tables you can change the owner using `ALTER TABLE` later.

At any rate, reading between the lines, that looks like what you are asking about.  `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` also works but the role you are trying to grant to could then be locked out by the owner of a given table.